# SQL Server 2008 to 2012 - Query Plan Compilation Time Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Ok very strange one this that is outside of my skill level unfortunately. We've got a fairly large database (35GB) with medium usage. This was on oldish hardware and SQL Server 2008. We got a new server, lots more ram / faster processors - great! HDD setup is the same (i.e. raid / configuration / file location). Backed up the database and restored on the new server (running in 2012 mode). Everything seemed fine - but all was not well. I'm getting very strange performance issues. Most queries are running slightly faster, which is great, but some queries on the first time are running a lot slower.

Example - we have a query that on initial run takes 7 seconds to complete. If I run it again it takes 250ms. If I change a parameter value it takes 7 seconds to run again. If I clear the query plan cache it takes 7 seconds to run again. If I run the same query on the old database, it takes 500ms on first run, 400ms on second run.

So something is defo up with how long it takes to compile the query. When I return the actual execution plan, its the same but the estimate rows / subtree costs are a lot higher on the new server. When I do properties and get the compile time its 7000 vs 350 on the old server (assuming thats ms).

If I amend the query and have options(recompile) it takes 3 seconds to run pretty much each and every time. So faster initial, but still too slow on recalls.

As part of the migration, rebuilt all indexes and updated statistics.

So long story short, new server is quicker but only after the query plan has been created. Ideas?

Not including any code, as the query isn't the problem - runs fine on SQL Server 2008 and runs fine on 2012 after initial run.
[Edit - Example of what I mean by variable. Between edits I'm just changing the 'something' to 'something1']

```
DECLARE @myReference VARCHAR(50) = 'something'
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM dbo.Table
WHERE Column3 = @myReference
```

[/Edit]

I would expect the general performance to be a slight improvement over 2008 due to the better hardware.

Image of profiler outputs: [profiler]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/baJ7Y.jpg "profiler image"

```
Confirmation of version: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4) (KB4018073) - 
11.0.7001.0 (X64)   Aug 15 2017 10:23:29   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard 
Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )
```

Comment: Are all the server settings the same between the setups?  You've compared all the general/advanced/memory/processor settings?

Comment: Please check if "optimize for ad hoc workloads" configuration is the same for old and new servers (compare run values by executind exec sp_configure 'optimize for ad hoc workloads')

Comment: Yeah all of the server settings are the same. The "optimize for ad hoc workloads" results from both servers are also the same.

Comment: The thing that is really perplexing is even changing the value of a parameter is causing a new plan to be created. Looking at performance issues around the net they seem to show that if you run the first batch with a value that isn't the normal and then run a normal value it can cause issues as the "wrong" plan is cached. Where as in my case a plan is cached every time I change the parameter value (not hardcoded - proper "@myvariable" type).

Comment: >>>even changing the value of a parameter is causing a new plan<<< Can you update your question with simple example of your "query"? The fact is that a simple query does not have any parameter. Do you mean constants or variables? Only sp and sp_executesql have PARAMETERS, other queries NO

Comment: I've updated the original post - cheers.

Comment: Please update your question with the result of select @@version

Answer (score 0):

Obviously that the problem is in a high compilation time.

Perhaps this issue is already addressed and fixed by MS.

Is the server updated to the latest Service Pack and cumulative update?
Is a trace 4199 enabled? SQL to enable:

```
DBCC TRACEON (4199, -1)
```

Long compilation time can be caused by large number of statistics, especially auto-created stats. Will removal of some of them adjust compilation time?

Recompilation also can be prevented by force parametrization:

```
ALTER DATABASE [your db] SET PARAMETERIZATION FORCED
```

However, it can improve current problematic query, while some other will suffer from parameter sniffing.

Comment: On the latest SP and version (11.0.7001.0). I've checked the trace flag and it's not enabled on either server. I've enable it for our test environment but there is no improvement (same behaviour; every time I change the value for a variable a new plan is created / compiled).

Comment: Added extra info, can you evaluate that also?

Comment: I've checked the values and both servers are the same (simple) so I don't really want to make the change as once the query runs it's rapid and worried about the consequences for all of the other queries run on the system.